# how to obtain ipv4 address of ubuntu server running in virtual box along with ipv6?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

i have installed ubuntu server on virtual box. When i execute the "ifconfig" command it shows the info of eth0 and loopback with inet6 address .but i want ipv4 address instead of ipv6 and i am not sure about the network adapter configuration of virtualbox as iam using wifi on my pc. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can guess you did bridge mode for Internet but , your dhcp not providing IP address to  your port or you have not enabled networking. so , it showing like this

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:11:32:db:1b:a5  
          inet6 addr: fe80::ea11:32ff:fedb:1ba5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:68323 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:51953 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:82498217 (82.4 MB)  TX bytes:4621046 (4.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9075 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9075 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:916870 (916.8 KB)  TX bytes:916870 (916.8 KB)
```

Solution: 
start your network-manager using

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

or use if already started

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

or

```
sudo ip link set eth0 up
```

or

```
sudo nmcli nm enable true
```

or enable using GUI

```
network-manager--> Enable Networking and connect wired connection
```

or

if you still face problem then it means your wifi dhcp not providing ip to VM then you can change mode `bridge` to `NAT` for internet then you will get private ip and will able to connect internet

Comment: check this out [link](http://postimg.org/image/3qjjwjz2l/)

Comment: okay thanks for ur patience!...still the webpage is waiting??

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the bridged mode, I had to disable ipv6 as per this post to get it working:
https://superuser.com/questions/1146122/ubuntu-virtualbox-guest-does-not-get-ipv4-in-bridged-mode/1148247#1148247?newreg=7c77aaf0882540148a3700242cd05d0b

Pasting the steps from above:
Open `/etc/default/grub`

In this file, find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 quiet splash"
```

Save the file and update GRUB by running:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now reboot the VM. Next time it comes up with appropriate ipv4 address.

Answer (score 0):

Could you ensure that you have set up your virtual interface with bridged mode?

If you are using a wireless connection, Vbox is not going to support IPv6 in bridged mode as you can see in Vbox manual:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged

Hope this helps.