# How to enable IPv4 on ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS server

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, virtualbox, dhcp

I have VirtualBox running on my ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS host.  I created a new virtual machine and set the network type to "Bridged Adapter". I then installed 16.04.1 LTS on the guest, but I cannot connect to any external IPv4 address from it.

When I run 'ifconfig', I only see my IPv6 address.

```
$ ifconfig enp0s3
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet6 addr: fd00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::xx:xx:xx:xx/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:933 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:751 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:101012 (101.0 KB)  TX bytes:144480 (144.4 KB)
```

I am able to SSH into the guest from the host using the IPv6 address.  I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667881/how-to-obtain-ipv4-address-of-ubuntu-server-running-in-virtual-box-along-with-ip) question, but I don't have network manager installed (and can't install it until IPv4 is working) and the only other command 'sudo ip link set enp0s3 up' didn't help.  Also, the question doesn't mention WiFi, but the answers seem to assume this is the case, and I am using wired connections instead of WiFi.

My /etc/network/interfaces file is pretty generic, but the comments do indicate that it is an IPv6 interface.  That said, I don't see why that is the case; all the parameters are correct for IPv4.

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

Notice in my neworking.service status,there is a 5 minute gap between starting to raise the network services, and actually doing so.  I am not sure what is going on there.

```
$ systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2017-06-14 09:33:00 EDT; 55min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 2335 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1947 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=
 Main PID: 2335 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/networking.service

Jun 14 09:27:58 chris-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Jun 14 09:28:01 chris-ubuntu ifup[2335]: /sbin/ifup: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.enp0s3
Jun 14 09:33:00 chris-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
```

When I manually run the dhclient, it hangs.  Syslog contains the following logs:

```
Jun 14 10:39:13 chris-ubuntu dhclient[3061]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x4dfcbf2b)
Jun 14 10:39:16 chris-ubuntu dhclient[2377]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x25d1c331)
Jun 14 10:39:20 chris-ubuntu dhclient[2377]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jun 14 10:39:20 chris-ubuntu dhclient[2377]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jun 14 10:39:23 chris-ubuntu dhclient[3061]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x4dfcbf2b)
```

This seems strange since the host VirtualBox is acting as the DHCP Server, so it should be responding.

Comment: Change VB settings from bridge to NAT. Your ISP probably does not give another IP address.

Comment: @Pilot6 Is this to test something or as a solution?  Because there is a reason I want to use bridged; I will be running a web server on the guest and need to access it from machines other than the host.  I would like to avoid setting up port forwarding if possible.

Comment: It depends on if your ISP gives more that 1 IP address. If not, you will have to use NAT and use port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need IPv4. The configuration above is little bit strange. (no public IPv6-Adresses). 
My first question to the admin of the network would be:
Do you provide a web-proxy? So you can change the proxy settings, including access to ipv4-only-hosts.
But I would prefer IPv6 global unicast addresses. In that case the DNS (DNS64/NAT64) solves the problem. A proxy would have a similar effect.